# How to create nested models in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

Going through Ember.js documentation, I am not able to figure out how to create nested models. Assume that I have the following JSON:

```
App.jsonObject = {
    id: 1812,
    name: 'Brokerage Account',
    positions: [
        {
            symbol: 'AAPL',
            quantity: '300'
        },
        {
            symbol: 'GOOG',
            quantity: '500'
        }
    ]
}
```

If I create a model object like this

```
App.account = Ember.Object.create(App.jsonObject);
```

only the top level properties (id and name) get bound to templates, the nested positions array does not get bound correctly. As a result adding, deleting or updating positions does not affect the display. Is there a manual or automatic way to transform the positions array so that it is binding aware (similar to an ObservableCollection in WPF)?

I have created a jsfiddle to experiment with this: http://jsfiddle.net/nareshbhatia/357sg/. As you can see, changes to top level properties are reflected in the output, but any change to the positions is not. I would greatly appreciate any hints on how to do this.

Thanks.

Naresh

**Edit:**
The ideal situation would be if Ember.js could somehow parse my JSON feed into nested Ember.js objects. For example, what if I explicitly define my classes as follows, could that assist Ember.js to create the right objects?

```
App.Account = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null,
    positions: Ember.ArrayProxy.create()
});

App.Position = Ember.Object.extend({
    symbol: null,
    quantity: null,
    lastTrade: null
});

App.account = App.Account.create(App.jsonObject);
```

My eventual goal is to display this structure in a hierarchical grid which can expand/collapse at the account level. Coming from the WPF/Silverlight world, it is fairly easy to do something like this. All you need to do is to specify a nested template for the grid in XAML and it knows how to interpret your model. You can find an example [here](https://code.google.com/p/archfirst/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/Projects/Bullsfirst/Silverlight/Bullsfirst.Module.Positions/Views/PositionsView.xaml) - it is not too difficult to follow. I am wondering if something like this is possible in Ember.js.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WPF or it's controls (haven't worked w/ it in almost 4 years), but it looks like something like that should be not too bad to implement in Ember & Handlebars.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `pushObject` not `push` when adding to Ember array objects with bindings. And you should probably use `get()` when accessing the `positions` property. See my jsFiddle for the corrections.

http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/Y5nG5/

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful as it allows me to treat positions as a first-class property. However, it still does not solve the problem with properties at the nested level (the one commented line near the end of my fiddle). I have edited my question to clarify my higher level goal. I would be really interested on your take on that. Thanks again.

Comment: For a nested array you'll have to iterate over the array and create Ember objects out of each of them. I don't think there is anything built into Ember that does this for you.

Comment: @Qrilka Don't know how that happened... I've corrected the link.

Comment: @RoyDaniels How can I render only object at a particular key , lets say 0? Array notation doesn't seem to work inside the template.

Comment: @Rajat That should be a separate question as it really doesn't have anything to do with the original question or solution. But enough with the StackOverflow etiquette, take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/MVqUU/)

Comment: Your Solution/fiddle worked perfectly for me but was wondering how I would access further nested data - for example

Answer (score 1):

I've created a recursive object factory that you may like:

It will iterate over the object and create Ember Arrays or nested objects, returning a full Ember Object tree!

Here is the source for your reference, and a JS fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/SEGwy/2/

Please note: the fiddle writes the output to the console, so you won't see any output on the screen.

```
  RecursiveObject = {

      // http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/
      TypeOf: function (input) {
          try {
              return Object.prototype.toString.call(input).match(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/)[1].toLowerCase();
          } catch (e) {
              return typeof input;
          }
      },

      // Factory method..
      create: function (args) {

          args = args || {};
          ctxt = this;

          switch (this.TypeOf(args)) {

              // Return an Ember Array
              case "array":

                  var result = Ember.A();

                  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                      x = this.create(args[i]);
                      result.push(x);
                  };

                  break;

              // Or a recursive object.
              case "object":

                  var result = Ember.Object.create();

                  $.each(args, function (key, value) {

                      result.set(key, ctxt.create(value));

                  });

                  break;

              default:

                  // Or just return the args.
                  result = args;
                  break;

          }

          return result;

      }

  }

  // Example

  jsonObject = {
    id: 1812,
    name: 'Brokerage Account',
    positions: [
        {
            symbol: 'AAPL',
            quantity: '300'
        },
        {
            symbol: 'GOOG',
            quantity: '500'
        }
    ]
  }

  x = RecursiveObject.create(jsonObject);
  console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own simple model factory based on Alexandros K's solution but supporting ES6 modules. Thought I would share it :)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var ModelFactory = Ember.Object.extend({});

ModelFactory.reopenClass({
    getType(obj) {
        if(!obj) {
            return null;
        }

        if(Array === obj.constructor) {
            return "array";
        }
        else if(typeof obj === "object") {
            return "object";
        }

        return null;
    },

    // Factory method..
    create: function (arg) {

        const _this = this;

        switch (this.getType(arg)) {

            // Return an Ember Array
            case "array":

                var newArray = [];

                arg.forEach(function(item) {
                    newArray.pushObject(_this.create(item));
                });

                return newArray;

            // Or a recursive object.
            case "object":

                var newObject = Ember.Object.create();

                for (var key in arg) {
                    if (arg.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        newObject.set(key, this.create(arg[key]));
                    }
                }

                return newObject;

            default:

                // Or just return the args.
                return arg;
        }
    }
});


export default ModelFactory;
```

Usage:

```
ModelFactory.create(json)
```

Answer (score -1):

## Answer relevant for Ember 2.5.0 / May 2016

I had a similar question (see below for my case) and was getting frustrated by the numerous out-dated / no-longer-helpful threads so am posting what I learned here in case it is helpful to others who stumble across this page.

**TL;DR:** In more recent versions of Ember you define your model by extending the `Model` object in ember-data with the attributes you want. The attributes are defined by calling [`DS.attr(type)`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/#method_attr) (where the `type` parameter can be omitted to pass through whatever types you want, e.g. nested objects from your JSON).

So for this question you could create `app/models/account` (possibly by using ember-cli --> `ember g resource account`):

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
    name: attr('string'),
    positions: hasMany('position')
});
```

and similarly for `app/models/position`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
    symbol: attr('string'),
    quantity: attr('number')
});
```

**My case:**

I wanted to have a `device` that is associated with a `connection` that might be a serial or TCP connection, each with different options/parameters. In plain JS, I would've done something like this:

```
[{
    name: "My serial device",
    connection: {
        type: "serial",
        options: {
            port: "COM1",
            baud: 115200,
            data_bits: 8,
            parity: "none",
            stop_bits: 1,
            flow_control: "none"
        }
    }
}, {
    name: "My TCP/IP device",
    connection: {
        type: "tcp",
        options: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 23
        }
    }
}]
```

in Ember this translates to a `device` model with a connection property whose type is an object (left unspecified):

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
    name: attr('string'),
    connection: attr()
});
```

If you're wondering what is a good criterion for determining whether something should be it's own model (with `belongsTo`, `hasMany`, etc. relationship) or not, a simple question to start with is whether or not the resource in question would otherwise have id numbers associated with it. In this case, it doesn't make much sense to track connections and devices separately, so I opted not to create a separate model for connections.