# Organize MVC with Tree structure in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, ember.js

I'm new to MVC, and I'm trying to figure out how to organize the following application with Ember.js -

Users create a family tree by dragging photos onto the page.  A photo dropped on a single person would become its mate, a sibling in the tree, and a photo dropped on a couple would become its child.  They can rename and edit properties about the photos by double clicking them and launching a modal that shows the properties of each person in text boxes.

Most of the examples of Ember I've found have bindings between instances of classes.  They don't work when you don't know how many instances and children each one will have.  How can I create a nested structure of with good MVC practices?  Would you use a ContainerView or ArrayProxy to manage children?

Create a new controller, object and view for each level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been talking about this with my colleagues. We considered polygamous relationships and the fact that people could have children with different partners... but then limited the scope to aid in productive discussion....

I started thinking about nested models as discussed here [How to create nested models in Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186214/how-to-create-nested-models-in-ember-js) but it seems we're really talking relational databases.

There is a good post at the link below about creating references between objects by given IDs, take a look - I think it's what you are looking for. You might also get some nice ideas about data persistence.
http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1345