# Ember - how to use pushObject on nested data object?

Tags: ember.js

I can already push a new object into the jobs and jobProducts array thanks to this post [How to create nested models in Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186214/how-to-create-nested-models-in-ember-js)

but I cannot seem to push new allocations or deliverys. I have included the JSON object below.

Any advice is appreciated, I will put together a fiddle of where I currently am when I get a moment.

Cheers

```
App.jobs = [
  {
    id: 0,
    jobTitle: "This is the only job",
    jobProducts: [
      {
        id: 0,
        productTitle: "Product 1",
        allocations:[
          {
            id: 0,
            allocationTitle: "Allocation 1",
            deliverys:[
              {
                id: 0,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 1"
              },
              {
                id: 1,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            allocationTitle: "Allocation 2",
            deliverys:[
              {
                id: 0,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 3"
              },
              {
                id: 1,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 4"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        productTitle: "Product 2",
        allocations:[
          {
            id: 0,
            allocationTitle: "Allocation 3",
            deliverys:[
              {
                id: 0,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 5"
              },
             {
               id: 1,
               deliveryTitle: "Delivery 6"
             }
           ]
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            allocationTitle: "Allocation 4",
            deliverys:[
              {
                id: 0,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 7"
              },
              {
                id: 1,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 8"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short:**

here is an example how you might do it: http://jsbin.com/esixeh/7/edit

**The long:**

In the example you will find code lines like the below, which look scary but it works:

```
App.get('jobs').objectAt(0).jobProducts.objectAt(0).allocations.objectAt(0).deliverys.pushObject({...});
```

Since down you JSON structure, starting from `App.get('jobs')` the objects are just plain javascript objects and do not extend from [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) you cannot use ember methods like `.get('allocations')` or `.get('deliverys')` on them and chain them together like:

```
App.get('jobs').get('jobProducts').get('allocations').get('deliverys');
```

or

```
App.get('jobs.jobProducts.allocations.deliverys');
```

but you can still use plain javascript dot notation accessor like `.allocations`.

On array's you can still use ember's `.pushObject()`, `.objectAt()` etc. instead of plain `.push()`, because array's are augmented by the framework by default [see here](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/) for more info on that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks this works great, makes sense now why I was getting an Object does not have the method get.