# Walking an object in a template

Tags: ember.js

One of my data models has this data structure:

```
properties : {
    ....
    locator_map : {
        locator1 : locator_doc_id1,
        locator2 : locator_doc_id2,
        ...
        locatorN : locator_doc_idN,
    },
    ...
}
```

In my template I want to provide links to those documents, but I do not know how to walk the object `locator_map`. I want to do something on these lines:

```
{{#each locator in this.properties.locator_map}}
    {{#linkTo "locators.show" this.properties.locator_map[locator]}}locator{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

But I have two problems:

1. "Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [object Object]"
2. How to access the value? I have the impression that `this.properties.locator_map[locator]` is not going to work.

Any idea how to walk the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is because almost everything in the ember framework extends from [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) but your `locator`'s do not, so you have two options:

1. Creating a custom handlebars `{{#each}}` helper which deals with your non [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html)'s
2. Parse your data coming back from the backend and convert the `locator_map` objects to [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html)'s this will make the objects then also binding aware etc.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115582/ember-how-to-use-pushobject-on-nested-data-object) I recently answered which deals with a similar case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Added a reply with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @intuitivepixel, this is my transform:

```
// Used to represent a generic key:value mapping
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('dict', {
    serialize: function(data) {
        var dict = {}, element;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            element = data[i];
            dict[element.get('key')] = element.get('value');
        }
        return dict;
    },
    deserialize: function(dict) {
        var data = Ember.A(), element;
        for (var key in dict) {
            data.push(Ember.create({ key: key, value: dict[key] }));
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

The model:

```
SettingsApp.ServiceProperties = SettingsApp.CommonProperties.extend({
    locator_map : DS.attr('dict'),

});

SettingsApp.Service = DS.Model.extend(SettingsApp.NodeMixin, {
    properties : DS.belongsTo('SettingsApp.ServiceProperties')
});
```

And the use on the template:

```
{{#each locator in this.properties.locator_map}}
    {{#linkTo "locators.show" locator.value}}{{locator.key}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```